# Issue trying to stream RTSP to RTMP (live) through NGINX

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtsp, live, rtmp

I want live RTMP streaming through nginx. I setup this server on a public ip (linux - CentOS), using this tutorial: https://notehub.org/rcfdu.

My target is: RTSP source -> transcode to RTMP -> recieve on nginx (live ip),

Then, I want to receive this stream through server; something like:

nginx -> ffplay.

On transmission side, I have ffmpeg application, and on receiver side, I have ffplay application.

I have setup everything I could think of, and I can see it is properly setup (apparently). But, when I try to stream using similar command:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://aaa.bb.ccc.ddd/vod/mp4:filename.mov -f mpegts rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
```

I get lots of messages (where everything looks alright):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://aaa.bb.ccc.ddd/vod/mp4:filename.mov -f mpegts rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
ffmpeg version N-80386-g5f5a97d Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-nv
enc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enabl
e-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --en
able-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libil
bc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-
amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-
librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-li
bspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo
-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libweb
p --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-l
ibzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[rtsp @ 03087ca0] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://aaa.bb.ccc.ddd/vod/mp4:filename.mov':
  Metadata:
    title           : filename.mov
  Duration: 00:09:56.46, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 240x160, 24 fps, 4
8 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
[mpegts @ 04d033a0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is d
eprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, mpegts, to 'rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/':
  Metadata:
    title           : filename.mov
    encoder         : Lavf57.38.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (Main), yuv420p, 240x160, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 2
4 fps, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 mpeg2video
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 384 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.46.100 mp2
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg2video (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> mp2 (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 4 times
frame=   85 fps=0.0 q=2.9 size=     322kB time=00:00:03.85 bitrate= 684.4kbits/s
frame=   95 fps= 94 q=3.5 size=     366kB time=00:00:04.28 bitrate= 698.9kbits/s
frame=  108 fps= 71 q=3.7 size=     421kB time=00:00:04.79 bitrate= 719.9kbits/s
frame=  122 fps= 61 q=4.1 size=     478kB time=00:00:05.34 bitrate= 733.1kbits/s
frame=  134 fps= 53 q=4.5 size=     527kB time=00:00:05.87 bitrate= 735.8kbits/s
frame=  146 fps= 48 q=5.2 size=     579kB time=00:00:06.35 bitrate= 747.2kbits/s
frame=  159 fps= 45 q=5.5 size=     632kB time=00:00:06.88 bitrate= 751.9kbits/s
frame=  171 fps= 42 q=5.3 size=     677kB time=00:00:07.38 bitrate= 751.5kbits/s
frame=  183 fps= 40 q=5.6 size=     725kB time=00:00:07.91 bitrate= 750.8kbits/s
frame=  193 fps= 38 q=6.3 size=     765kB time=00:00:08.34 bitrate= 750.7kbits/s
frame=  207 fps= 37 q=6.6 size=     820kB time=00:00:08.89 bitrate= 755.2kbits/s
frame=  219 fps= 36 q=6.6 size=     865kB time=00:00:09.40 bitrate= 754.2kbits/s
frame=  231 fps= 35 q=7.2 size=     911kB time=00:00:09.90 bitrate= 753.6kbits/s
frame=  243 fps= 34 q=7.4 size=     959kB time=00:00:10.40 bitrate= 754.6kbits/s
frame=  255 fps= 34 q=6.7 size=    1002kB time=00:00:10.91 bitrate= 752.1kbits/s
frame=  267 fps= 33 q=5.5 size=    1047kB time=00:00:11.41 bitrate= 751.4kbits/s
frame=  279 fps= 33 q=4.6 size=    1088kB time=00:00:11.89 bitrate= 749.1kbits/s
frame=  291 fps= 32 q=6.1 size=    1140kB time=00:00:12.42 bitrate= 751.4kbits/s
frame=  301 fps= 31 q=6.7 size=    1181kB time=00:00:12.85 bitrate= 752.5kbits/s
frame=  314 fps= 31 q=6.6 size=    1231kB time=00:00:13.40 bitrate= 752.1kbits/s
frame=  325 fps= 31 q=7.0 size=    1275kB time=00:00:13.86 bitrate= 753.0kbits/s
frame=  338 fps= 30 q=6.7 size=    1324kB time=00:00:14.36 bitrate= 754.8kbits/s
frame=  349 fps= 30 q=6.5 size=    1368kB time=00:00:14.87 bitrate= 753.5kbits/s
frame=  362 fps= 30 q=6.8 size=    1415kB time=00:00:15.37 bitrate= 753.9kbits/s
frame=  373 fps= 30 q=6.2 size=    1457kB time=00:00:15.88 bitrate= 751.7kbits/s
frame=  387 fps= 30 q=3.8 size=    1506kB time=00:00:16.45 bitrate= 749.7kbits/s
frame=  400 fps= 29 q=4.1 size=    1549kB time=00:00:16.96 bitrate= 748.2kbits/s
frame=  415 fps= 29 q=5.4 size=    1597kB time=00:00:17.56 bitrate= 744.9kbits/s
frame=  427 fps= 29 q=5.2 size=    1639kB time=00:00:18.04 bitrate= 744.1kbits/s
frame=  439 fps= 29 q=4.4 size=    1679kB time=00:00:18.56 bitrate= 740.6kbits/s
frame=  451 fps= 29 q=3.6 size=    1717kB time=00:00:19.07 bitrate= 737.4kbits/s
frame=  464 fps= 28 q=2.6 size=    1761kB time=00:00:19.67 bitrate= 733.2kbits/s
frame=  475 fps= 28 q=7.0 size=    1799kB time=00:00:20.08 bitrate= 734.0kbits/s
frame=  488 fps= 28 q=8.3 size=    1847kB time=00:00:20.70 bitrate= 730.8kbits/s
frame=  502 fps= 28 q=5.9 size=    1895kB time=00:00:21.25 bitrate= 730.2kbits/s
frame=  515 fps= 28 q=3.3 size=    1935kB time=00:00:21.76 bitrate= 728.5kbits/s
frame=  528 fps= 28 q=2.5 size=    1976kB time=00:00:22.31 bitrate= 725.6kbits/s
frame=  540 fps= 28 q=3.4 size=    2017kB time=00:00:22.81 bitrate= 724.2kbits/s
frame=  553 fps= 28 q=6.2 size=    2072kB time=00:00:23.36 bitrate= 726.2kbits/s
frame=  568 fps= 28 q=6.7 size=    2132kB time=00:00:23.94 bitrate= 729.3kbits/s
frame=  580 fps= 28 q=6.8 size=    2174kB time=00:00:24.42 bitrate= 729.3kbits/s
frame=  592 fps= 27 q=6.8 size=    2219kB time=00:00:24.92 bitrate= 729.3kbits/s
frame=  604 fps= 27 q=7.4 size=    2263kB time=00:00:25.43 bitrate= 728.8kbits/s
frame=  615 fps= 27 q=6.1 size=    2305kB time=00:00:25.93 bitrate= 727.9kbits/s
frame=  626 fps= 27 q=7.4 size=    2339kB time=00:00:26.36 bitrate= 726.5kbits/s
frame=  638 fps= 27 q=6.8 size=    2383kB time=00:00:26.89 bitrate= 725.8kbits/s
frame=  651 fps= 27 q=5.8 size=    2436kB time=00:00:27.47 bitrate= 726.5kbits/s
frame=  662 fps= 27 q=7.0 size=    2471kB time=00:00:27.90 bitrate= 725.4kbits/s
frame=  675 fps= 27 q=5.9 size=    2523kB time=00:00:28.40 bitrate= 727.6kbits/s
frame=  679 fps= 26 q=6.8 size=    2534kB time=00:00:28.57 bitrate= 726.5kbits/s
frame=  703 fps= 27 q=8.0 size=    2622kB time=00:00:29.58 bitrate= 726.1kbits/s
frame=  714 fps= 27 q=7.6 size=    2662kB time=00:00:30.08 bitrate= 724.7kbits/s
frame=  729 fps= 27 q=6.5 size=    2712kB time=00:00:30.68 bitrate= 724.0kbits/s
frame=  741 fps= 27 q=7.0 size=    2753kB time=00:00:31.14 bitrate= 724.1kbits/s
frame=  755 fps= 27 q=7.5 size=    2801kB time=00:00:31.76 bitrate= 722.2kbits/s
frame=  767 fps= 26 q=7.2 size=    2842kB time=00:00:32.27 bitrate= 721.5kbits/s
frame=  779 fps= 26 q=6.8 size=    2881kB time=00:00:32.77 bitrate= 720.0kbits/s
frame=  791 fps= 26 q=8.2 size=    2922kB time=00:00:33.30 bitrate= 718.8kbits/s
frame=  803 fps= 26 q=7.0 size=    2961kB time=00:00:33.76 bitrate= 718.4kbits/s
frame=  816 fps= 26 q=6.6 size=    3003kB time=00:00:34.33 bitrate= 716.4kbits/s
frame=  828 fps= 26 q=6.4 size=    3044kB time=00:00:34.84 bitrate= 715.7kbits/s
frame=  840 fps= 26 q=7.5 size=    3084kB time=00:00:35.34 bitrate= 714.7kbits/s
frame=  855 fps= 26 q=5.0 size=    3137kB time=00:00:35.94 bitrate= 714.8kbits/s
frame=  866 fps= 26 q=6.2 size=    3169kB time=00:00:36.40 bitrate= 713.3kbits/s
frame=  880 fps= 26 q=5.9 size=    3219kB time=00:00:36.95 bitrate= 713.6kbits/s
frame=  892 fps= 26 q=6.8 size=    3259kB time=00:00:37.43 bitrate= 713.2kbits/s
frame=  904 fps= 26 q=5.3 size=    3300kB time=00:00:37.96 bitrate= 712.2kbits/s
frame=  916 fps= 26 q=5.5 size=    3338kB time=00:00:38.46 bitrate= 711.0kbits/s
frame=  928 fps= 26 q=5.5 size=    3377kB time=00:00:38.94 bitrate= 710.4kbits/s
frame=  941 fps= 26 q=6.4 size=    3422kB time=00:00:39.52 bitrate= 709.4kbits/s
frame=  953 fps= 26 q=5.4 size=    3460kB time=00:00:40.00 bitrate= 708.6kbits/s
frame=  967 fps= 26 q=5.2 size=    3506kB time=00:00:40.60 bitrate= 707.3kbits/s
frame=  979 fps= 26 q=4.8 size=    3546kB time=00:00:41.12 bitrate= 706.2kbits/s
frame=  985 fps= 26 q=5.2 size=    3563kB time=00:00:41.36 bitrate= 705.6kbits/s
frame= 1008 fps= 26 q=4.8 size=    3639kB time=00:00:42.30 bitrate= 704.6kbits/s
frame= 1022 fps= 26 q=4.3 size=    3684kB time=00:00:42.88 bitrate= 703.7kbits/s
frame= 1034 fps= 26 q=4.5 size=    3723kB time=00:00:43.38 bitrate= 702.9kbits/s
frame= 1046 fps= 26 q=3.8 size=    3763kB time=00:00:43.88 bitrate= 702.5kbits/s
frame= 1056 fps= 26 q=5.3 size=    3800kB time=00:00:44.32 bitrate= 702.3kbits/s
frame= 1069 fps= 26 q=5.5 size=    3842kB time=00:00:44.84 bitrate= 701.8kbits/s
frame= 1081 fps= 26 q=6.3 size=    3883kB time=00:00:45.35 bitrate= 701.3kbits/s
frame= 1093 fps= 26 q=6.3 size=    3925kB time=00:00:45.85 bitrate= 701.1kbits/s
frame= 1105 fps= 26 q=5.3 size=    3964kB time=00:00:46.36 bitrate= 700.5kbits/s
frame= 1117 fps= 26 q=6.7 size=    4006kB time=00:00:46.86 bitrate= 700.3kbits/s
frame= 1129 fps= 26 q=4.5 size=    4046kB time=00:00:47.32 bitrate= 700.4kbits/s
frame= 1141 fps= 26 q=7.1 size=    4089kB time=00:00:47.87 bitrate= 699.8kbits/s
Larger timestamp than 24-bit: 0x310042f0
WriteN, RTMP send error 10054 (133 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10054 (35 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10038 (42 bytes)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
Error writing trailer of rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/: Operation not permitte
dframe= 1143 fps= 25 q=8.1 Lsize=    4109kB time=00:00:47.92 bitrate= 702.5kbits
/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.07x
video:1343kB audio:2248kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxi
ng overhead: 14.429363%
Conversion failed!
```

but in the end, I get this error:

```
WriteN, RTMP send error 10054 (133 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10054 (35 bytes)
WriteN, RTMP send error 10038 (42 bytes)
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Operation not permitted
Error writing trailer of rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/: Operation not permitte
dframe= 1143 fps= 25 q=8.1 Lsize=    4109kB time=00:00:47.92 bitrate= 702.5kbits
/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.07x
video:1343kB audio:2248kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxi
ng overhead: 14.429363%
Conversion failed!
```

On the receiver side (where ffplay is running), I always get this error:

```
RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet headersq=    0B f=0/0
    rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Detailed output:

```
ffplay rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
ffplay version N-80386-g5f5a97d Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-nv
enc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enabl
e-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --en
able-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libil
bc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-
amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-
librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-li
bspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo
-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libweb
p --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-l
ibzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet headersq=    0B f=0/0
rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/: Invalid data found when processing input
```

and if I enable debug mode, this is the receiving side log:

```
ffplay -loglevel debug rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
ffplay version N-80386-g5f5a97d Copyright (c) 2003-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-nv
enc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enabl
e-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --en
able-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libil
bc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-
amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-
librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-li
bspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo
-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libweb
p --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-l
ibzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 24.100 / 55. 24.100
  libavcodec     57. 46.100 / 57. 46.100
  libavformat    57. 38.100 / 57. 38.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 46.101 /  6. 46.101
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[rtmp @ 0310d800] No default whitelist set    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
Parsing... :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
Parsed protocol: 0
Parsed host    : <live ip address>
Parsed app     : live
RTMP_Connect1, ... connected, handshaking=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
HandShake: Type Answer   : 03q=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
HandShake: Server Uptime : 324510454
HandShake: FMS Version   : 0.0.0.0
HandShake: Handshaking finished....0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
RTMP_Connect1, handshaked
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=174
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 ae 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 07 63 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ...connect.?....
  0010:  00 00 00 03 00 03 61 70  70 02 00 04 6c 69 76 65   ......app...live
  0020:  00 05 74 63 55 72 6c 02  00 1e 72 74 6d 70 3a 2f   ..tcUrl...rtmp:/
  0030:  2f 36 34 2e 34 39 2e 32  33 34 2e 32 35 30 3a 31   /<live ip address>:1
  0040:  39 33 35 2f 6c 69 76 65  00 04 66 70 61 64 01 00   935/live..fpad..
  0050:  00 0c 63 61 70 61 62 69  6c 69 74 69 65 73 00 40   ..capabilities.@
  0060:  2e 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  0b 61 75 64 69 6f 43 6f   .........audioCo
  0070:  64 65 63 73 00 40 a8 ee  00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 76   decs.@.........v
  0000:  c3                                                 .
  0000:  69 64 65 6f 43 6f 64 65  63 73 00 40 6f 80 00 00   ideoCodecs.@o...
  0010:  00 00 00 00 0d 76 69 64  65 6f 46 75 6e 63 74 69   .....videoFuncti
  0020:  6f 6e 00 3f f0 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 09         on.?..........
Invoking connect
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 04 05  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 4c 4b 40                                        .LK@
HandleServerBW: server BW = 5000000
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 05 06  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 4c 4b 40 02                                     .LK@.
HandleClientBW: client BW = 5000000 2
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 04 01  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 00 10 00                                        ....
HandleChangeChunkSize, received: chunk size change to 4096
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 be 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 07 5f 72 65 73 75  6c 74 00 3f f0 00 00 00   ..._result.?....
  0010:  00 00 00 03 00 06 66 6d  73 56 65 72 02 00 0d 46   ......fmsVer...F
  0020:  4d 53 2f 33 2c 30 2c 31  2c 31 32 33 00 0c 63 61   MS/3,0,1,123..ca
  0030:  70 61 62 69 6c 69 74 69  65 73 00 40 3f 00 00 00   pabilities.@?...
  0040:  00 00 00 00 00 09 03 00  05 6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00   .........level..
  0050:  06 73 74 61 74 75 73 00  04 63 6f 64 65 02 00 1d   .status..code...
  0060:  4e 65 74 43 6f 6e 6e 65  63 74 69 6f 6e 2e 43 6f   NetConnection.Co
  0070:  6e 6e 65 63 74 2e 53 75  63 63 65 73 73 00 0b 64   nnect.Success..d
  0080:  65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69  6f 6e 02 00 15 43 6f 6e   escription...Con
  0090:  6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 20  73 75 63 63 65 65 64 65   nection succeede
  00a0:  64 2e 00 0e 6f 62 6a 65  63 74 45 6e 63 6f 64 69   d...objectEncodi
  00b0:  6e 67 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 09         ng............
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 190 bytes
(object begin)
Property: <Name:           no-name., STRING:    _result>
Property: <Name:           no-name., NUMBER:    1.00>
Property: <Name:           no-name., OBJECT>
(object begin)
Property: <Name:             fmsVer, STRING:    FMS/3,0,1,123>
Property: <Name:       capabilities, NUMBER:    31.00>
(object end)
Property: <Name:           no-name., OBJECT>
(object begin)
Property: <Name:              level, STRING:    status>
Property: <Name:               code, STRING:    NetConnection.Connect.Success>
Property: <Name:        description, STRING:    Connection succeeded.>
Property: <Name:     objectEncoding, NUMBER:    0.00>
(object end)
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking <_result>
HandleInvoke, received result for method call <connect>  0B f=0/0
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=4
  0000:  02 00 00 00 00 00 04 05  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  00 4c 4b 40                                        .LK@
sending ctrl. type: 0x0003
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=10
  0000:  42 00 00 00 00 00 0a 04                            B.......
  0000:  00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 2c                     .........,
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=25
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 19 14                            C.......
  0000:  02 00 0c 63 72 65 61 74  65 53 74 72 65 61 6d 00   ...createStream.
  0010:  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  05                        @........
Invoking createStream
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  03 00 00 00 00 00 1d 14  00 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 07 5f 72 65 73 75  6c 74 00 40 00 00 00 00   ..._result.@....
  0010:  00 00 00 05 00 3f f0 00  00 00 00 00 00            .....?.......
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 29 bytes
(object begin)
Property: <Name:           no-name., STRING:    _result>
Property: <Name:           no-name., NUMBER:    2.00>
Property: NULL
Property: <Name:           no-name., NUMBER:    1.00>
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking <_result>
HandleInvoke, received result for method call <createStream>
SendPlay, seekTime=0, stopTime=0, sending play: (null)
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=29
  0000:  08 00 00 00 00 00 1d 14  01 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 04 70 6c 61 79 00  40 08 00 00 00 00 00 00   ...play.@.......
  0010:  05 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00            .............
Invoking play 0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
sending ctrl. type: 0x0003
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=10
  0000:  c2                                                 .
  0000:  00 03 00 00 00 01 00 00  0b b8                     ..........
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  05 00 00 00 00 00 60 14  01 00 00 00               ......`.....
  0000:  02 00 08 6f 6e 53 74 61  74 75 73 00 00 00 00 00   ...onStatus.....
  0010:  00 00 00 00 05 03 00 05  6c 65 76 65 6c 02 00 06   ........level...
  0020:  73 74 61 74 75 73 00 04  63 6f 64 65 02 00 14 4e   status..code...N
  0030:  65 74 53 74 72 65 61 6d  2e 50 6c 61 79 2e 53 74   etStream.Play.St
  0040:  61 72 74 00 0b 64 65 73  63 72 69 70 74 69 6f 6e   art..description
  0050:  02 00 0a 53 74 61 72 74  20 6c 69 76 65 00 00 09   ...Start live...
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: invoke 96 bytes
(object begin)
Property: <Name:           no-name., STRING:    onStatus>
Property: <Name:           no-name., NUMBER:    0.00>
Property: NULL
Property: <Name:           no-name., OBJECT>
(object begin)
Property: <Name:              level, STRING:    status>
Property: <Name:               code, STRING:    NetStream.Play.Start>
Property: <Name:        description, STRING:    Start live>
(object end)
(object end)
HandleInvoke, server invoking <onStatus>
HandleInvoke, onStatus: NetStream.Play.Start
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
  0000:  05 00 00 00 00 00 18 12  01 00 00 00               ............
  0000:  02 00 11 7c 52 74 6d 70  53 61 6d 70 6c 65 41 63   ...|RtmpSampleAc
  0010:  63 65 73 73 01 01 01 01                            cess....
RTMP_ClientPacket, received: notify 24 bytes
(object begin)
Property: <Name:           no-name., STRING:    |RtmpSampleAccess>
Property: <Name:           no-name., BOOLEAN:   TRUE>    nan    :  0.000 fd=   0
 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
Property: <Name:           no-name., BOOLEAN:   TRUE>
(object end)
RTMP_ReadPacket: fd=648
RTMPSockBuf_Fill, recv returned -1. GetSockError(): 10060 (Unknown error)
RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
[AVIOContext @ 04c81be0] Statistics: 0 bytes read, 0 seeks
RTMP_SendPacket: fd=648, size=34
  0000:  43 00 00 00 00 00 22 14                            C.....".
  0000:  02 00 0c 64 65 6c 65 74  65 53 74 72 65 61 6d 00   ...deleteStream.
  0010:  40 10 00 00 00 00 00 00  05 00 3f f0 00 00 00 00   @.........?.....
  0020:  00 00                                              ..
Invoking deleteStreamd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/: Invalid data found when processing input
```

By the way, this is my server config file ( /etc/nginx/nginx.conf )

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  4;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
rtmp {
        server {
                listen 1935;
                chunk_size 4096;

                application live {
                        live on;
                        record off;
                }
        }
}
```

I can telnet into both port 80 and 1935, and made sure port 1935 is open as input and output in iptables...

```
-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
```

but nothing works.

Can anyone help in this regards?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found the issue:

I was using this command to stream through ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:pass@aaa.bb.ccc.dd:554/channel3 -f mpegts rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
```

The encoding parameters were incorrect: -f mpegts was wrong; I changed it to: -c copy -f flv , then it started working.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://admin:pass@aaa.bb.ccc.dd:554/channel3 -c copy -f flv rtmp://<live ip address>:1935/live/
```

Above example is for reading an RTSP based IP camera.